# Duplicating Data per number cycle

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to duplicate data down a set of columns based on number cycle. Every time a number in sequence repeats, I'd like the number IM populating to increase by 1.

For example:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |

Every time column B repeats its cycle, In this case when it repeats back to 1, 2 ect. I'd like column A to increase by 1.

Initially I thought something like `=IF(A3<>A2,B2+1,B2)` would suffice, but that repeats.

Is there a different formula I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: You say "increase by 1" but your progression is 1, 2, 4.  Are you trying to do a linear increase or an exponential one?  (n vs 2^(n-1))

Comment: Do you mean `=IF(B2=1,A1+1,A1)` in `A2` copied down?

Comment: Is the first or last number in the sequence always the same? If so, are the numbers in the sequence always unique?

Comment: @skin The list of numbers in column B always repeat, but I need column A to increase down by 1 every cycle through of column B. Eg when 1 repeats, column A will increase by 1

Comment: @Zsql1, I already understood that part but you didn’t answer my question. Are the numbers in column B for each sequence unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your scenario, I'd do this.

These formulas need to originate in cell **A2**.  If you're not working in the top left hand corner of your sheet, you'll need to adjust the formula accordingly.

**Scenario 1 - All numbers in the sequence are unique.**

```
=IF(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,B2),"1","") & "1") = B2, MAX($A$1:A1) + 1, MAX($A$1:A1))
```

[image: Scenario 1]

**Scenario 2 - All numbers in the sequence are *NOT* unique.**

```
=IF(SUMIF($A$1:A1, MAX($A$1:A1), $A$1:A1) / 6 = MAX($A$1:A1), MAX($A$1:A1) + 1, MAX($A$1:A1))
```

[image: Scenario 2]